# Multiple AJAX request at the same time slows down ASP.NET WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await, task-parallel-library, c#-5.0

I have multiple ajax requests going on (5 of them). They do different things but all of them at the end are fetching data from the database.
If there is only one call at some particular time they take no more than one second. All of them are similar, whichever I call, as long it's the only request running, it will take no more than 1-2 seconds in worst scenario (usually  about 700ms).
But I have dashboard page and 5 request at the same time. If I open chrome debugger I can see this :
[image]

Ok, it seems these requests are async from browser point of view so I decided to use async web api methods. They look something like this:

```
public async Task<List<NightsSoldGraphInfo>> NightsSold(
                      [FromUri]NightsSoldGraphCriteria criteria)
{
   CompressResponse();
   var results = await statisticsRepository.GetNightsSoldGraphData(UserPK, criteria);
   return results;
}
```

`GetNightsSoldGraphData` repository method look something like this:

```
public async Task<List<NightsSoldGraphInfo>> GetNightsSoldGraphData(
                  PrimaryKey userPk, 
                  NightsSoldGraphCriteria criteria)
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (ADatabase db = new ADatabase(connectionString))
        {
            //SOME DATABASE STUFF
        }
     }
 }
```

I converted 3 calls to async version and I thought I should notice performance boost. How to make each call take about one second (if that is the time each request takes when run alone)

This is what I get when this method is run alone (when everything else was loaded and user simply changed nights sold filter to get filtered data)
[image]
500ms. Very good. But how to make it 500ms when they are multiple ajax call to server? Why in the first example it took 5 seconds?

Is it because I'm ussing session to get user data, notice UserPK which is varibale that accesses session?

Answer (score 2):

> But how to make it 500ms when they are multiple ajax call to server?
>   Why in the first example it took 5 seconds?

What you've done is create an async over sync wrapper. That is an [anti-pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx). You're using thread-pool threads to do blocking work, and that doesn't scale well. If you want to be able to properly scale, there are a couple of factors to that.

First of all, use naturally asynchronous APIs. For example, Entity Framework (Version 6 and above) expose async endpoints in the form of `ToListAsync` and `FirstOrDefaultAsync`, etc. Don't spin new threads using `Task.Run`, you don't need that. It's actually contributing to the fact you see poor performance when trying to scale:

```
public async Task<List<NightsSoldGraphInfo>> GetNightsSoldGraphData(
                        PrimaryKey userPk, 
                        NightsSoldGraphCriteria criteria)
{
    using (ADatabase db = new ADatabase(connectionString))
    {
       var entities = await db.SomeTable.Where(x => x.UserKey == userPk)
                                  .ToListAsync();
       return entities;
    }
 }
```

Another factor is the which tables you're querying concurrently. If any of them are doing write operations and some read, there maybe synchronization involved at the database level. This means you'll have to rethink which tables are queried when, in order to be able to provide the best scale.

Comment: I am not able to move to EF just like that. Ok, I will just remove async stuff and cry few minutes :)

Comment: What DB provider are you using?

Comment: I'm using BL toolkit.